# How can I put a 64-bit user control into Visual Studio 2012's toolbox?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, controls

My Visual Studio 2012 project may end up being memory-intensive, so I have built all of the projects in its solution for a 64-bit processor.  There was at least one project (unfortunately I don't remember which) that was left at "Any CPU".  I decided to convert the contents of a form to a user control.  It built successfully, and I was able to add the resulting DLL to the toolbox and then drag the new control onto a form.

However, I was getting ugly warnings about mismatches between processor selections.  To clean them up, I changed all projects to target 64-bit processors.  Suddenly, I could not use my 64-bit control on my forms.  Research revealed one article that said that Visual Studio is a 32-bit process, and therefore it could not host 64-bit controls in the toolbox, but it is still possible to use those controls dynamically.  But the KB article I found dated back to the days of VS 2008.

Is this still true in VS 2012?  How can I get my 64-bit control into the toolbox so I can drag and drop it onto a form?

Thank you very much.

Comment: You can't.  There is never any point in targeting x64.  The choice is purely up the user's operating system on which your code runs, you don't control that from Visual Studio.  AnyCPU is the appropriate choice, you'll automatically run in 64-bit mode when the user's Windows edition is 64-bit.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  Unfortunately, that's not quite true in my case.  Almost all of our customers use the PostgreSQL database provider, but because not all of them do, we use ODBC in our programs.  PostgreSQL ODBC drivers don't like "any CPU".  They will raise processor mismatch errors if you try building for one processor and use an ODBC driver for the other, and if you select "any CPU", you get that error no matter which ODBC driver you choose.

Comment: It is not an error, just a warning.  Don't use the 64-bit *reference* assemblies if you don't want to see the warning, the 32-bit ones are fine.   The ones that matter are the actual assemblies that you deploy.

Answer (score 1):

Solution:
Add a Class Library to your Solution - Use the Any CPU flag to compile.
Move your UserControls to this library.
Add a reference in your x64 project to this library.
Build the solution, and then the UserControls are available in your x64 designers.

Comment: As I understand it, if you create custom controls in 32-bit V. Studio and expect to drag them onto a form, then the controls will be 32-bit, won't they?  Thus aren't you inadvertently forcing the application to run under 32-bit emulation mode on 64-bit computers?  I've not found a work-around yet.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this when writing an application using 64-bit Oracle.DataAccess.  The solution then had to become 64-bit, leading to the usual problem with 64-bit controls not being draggable from the Toolbox onto forms.  I ended up making all components that had a Designer build with AnyCPU, but the rest of the application as x64.  Worked perfectly.